# Error 1935 (image included)

Tags: windows-7, c++, visual-basic, installshield, redistributable

I'm having an issue where the Error 1935 comes up every time I try to install Adobe, Open Office, AutoDesk, or anything that uses InstallShield. This has gotten too intrusive to ignore for any longer. How do I fix the error present in the image below:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8529102/1935.png

I've tried the following:

- Reboot
- Rename m?coree.dll
- Install under Safe Mode (which doesn't work very well at all)
- Uninstall, clean, reinstall VBC++ Redist.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of redistributables have you installed? It's not VB, it's rather [VC8](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=32bc1bee-a3f9-4c13-9c99-220b62a191ee&displaylang=en)

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following two articles for possible solutions:

[Error 1935 when you install Acrobat 8.1 or Adobe Reader (8.1 or later on Windows Vista)](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/403/kb403465.html)

[How to fix Error 1935 in Microsoft Office](http://www.ehow.com/how_6159965_fix-error-1935-microsoft-office.html)

Although the articles relate to other products, the solutions they propose are quite general.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a corrupt log of Windows Update.
Running [Windows Update Troubleshooter](https://support.microsoft.com/es-ec/help/4027322/windows-update-troubleshooter) was the solution for me.